# Check a format of a line read in stdin to be number^number

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc, getline

I want to write a program in c that reads a line from stdin using `getline` in a `while` loop.
if the line of characters has the format "number^number" then it computes the result and print it. For instance if the user types 33^2 then it will print 1089. So I am wondering how can I check if the format is correct otherwise it returns a message of error to `stderr` and the user has to enter another line. I know that I have to use `strtol` to convert char to long.

Also, I am wondering how to use `getline` to read `stdin`. I only know how to use `fgets`.

Here is the portion of code that I have tried and it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long power(long, long);

long power(long x, long y) {

  if (y == 0) {
    return 1;
    }
    else {
    return x*power(x, y-1);
    }
}

int main(void) {

char *line =(char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
char *number1=(char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
char *number2=(char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
long x;
long y;

printf("User please enter The following format number1^number2\n");
int index;
int length;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)!= NULL) { // I want to use getline instead
length=strlen(line);
index = strchr(line,"^")-line; //find the index of "^" in the line

if ((index<0) || (index!=0) || (index!= length-1)) {
  fprintf(stderr,"The format is wrong it should be number1^number2\n");
}
else{
for (int i=0; i<index; i++) {
number1[i]=line[i];
}
for (int j=index+1; j<length; j++) {
number1[j]=line[j];
}
x=strtol(number1);
y=strtol(number2);
printf("%ld^%ld = %ld\n",x,y,power(x,y));
}

}



  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am also wondering how can I free the memory that I have allocated for all the dynamic array at every iteration in `while`.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: `while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)!= NULL) {` sizeof works different than you think.

Comment: 1) `strchr(line,"^")` --> `strchr(line, '^')` 2) `if ((index<0) || (index!=0) || (index!= length-1)) {` Bad conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//ssize_t getline(char **linep, size_t *n, FILE *fp);

unsigned long power(unsigned long base, unsigned long exp) {
    unsigned long result = 1;
    while(exp > 0){
        if(exp & 1)
            result = result * base;
        base = base * base;
        exp >>=1;
    }
    return result;//Overflow is not considered
}

int main(void) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    unsigned long x;
    unsigned long y;

    printf("User please enter The following format number1^number2\n");
    while(getline(&line, &size, stdin)!=-1){
        if(2!=sscanf(line, "%lu^%lu", &x, &y)){
            fprintf(stderr,"The format is wrong it should be number1^number2\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%lu^%lu = %lu\n", x, y, power(x,y));
    }
    free(line);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works perfectly!!
I just have a question regarding freeing the memory.. Could you tell me when we use the command `free` and how we use it after using `malloc`. Is there a way how to free the memory at every iteration inside the while loop?

Comment: @user2987 `getline` is not than to secure new memory every time it is called. 
So the release of in a loop is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string with `sscanf()`

```
int res = sscanf(line, "%d^%d", &n1, &n2);
```

After this, you can check res var. If res = 2, you parse the correct number of arguments. Then you can call your function to compute n1^n2.

Edit : you must not cast mallocs.

For getline :

```
char *line = null
int n = 0; /* If n = 0 getline will automaticely allocate the right memory */
getline(&line, &n, stdin)
```

Dont forget to `free()` your line

Comment: getline's 2nd argument type is `size_t*`.